# How to determine the function from the following?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives

The graph of a certain function contains the point $ (0,2)$ and has the property that for each number 'p' the line tangent to $y = f(x)$ at $(p, f(p))$ intersect the x-axis at p + 2. Find $f(x)$
The tangent to this equation at point $p$ is
$$y-f(p)=f'(p)(x-p) $$
putting $y =0$ and $x=p+2$ 
$$\frac{f'(p)}{f(p)}=-\frac{1}{2} $$
Now integrating
$$\int\frac{f'(p)}{f(p)}dp=-\frac{1}{2}\int dp $$ 
$$ln f(p)=\frac{-p}{2}+c $$
$$ f(p)=e^{\frac{-p}{2}+c} $$
From the point $(0,2)$ we get 
$$f(p)=2e^{\frac{-p}{2}} $$so $$f(x)=2e^{\frac{-x}{2}} $$
But the answer given is $f(x)=2e^{-x} $. What mistake I have done?

Comment: For what it's worth, I wasn't able to find any holes in your argument - are you sure the answer given is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textbook answer has a mistake. They probably wrote $f'(p)/f(p)=-2$ where it should be $f'(p)/f(p)=-{1\over 2}$. You can see that their answer is wrong because the tangent line to the graph of $f(x)=2e^{-x}$ at $x=0$ is $y=2-2x$, which intersects the $x$-axis at $x=1$, and not at $x=2$, as the assumption indicates.

Comment: How you got the equation $y=2-2x$

Comment: The tangent to $(0,f(0))$ is $y-f(0)=f'(0)x$, with $f(0)=2$ and $f'(0)=-2$ (because $f(x)=2e^{-x}$ is assumed).